# Hooking into "root" route in new Ember rc1 router

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I'm looking for a way to hook into the router as it transitions to any given leaf resource *during app init*.  In other words, I want to run a little init routine every single time an app is loaded, no matter what the "incoming" url state is.

Given a router such as this:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "donkeys"
  @resource "camels"
```

When the app is loaded (for the first time) with a dangling url such as this:

*localhost:9000/#/donkeys*

-- or --

*localhost:9000/#/camels*

I want the same router-level code to be called.

My first guess was to try something like this (**this doesn't work**):

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  activate: ->
    App.callTheBeastsOfBurden()
```

... but it turns out that IndexRoute is not being traversed. I only see the log message `Transitioned into 'donkeys'`

In ye olde days, there was this "root route" concept that you could hook in to.  If I recall, it looked something like this (**this is old and "wrong"**):

```
App.Router = Em.Router.extend
  root: Em.Route.extend
    connectOutlets: ->
      App.callTheBeastsOfBurden()
```

So what's the **Router v2 approved** method of accomplishing the same?

Comment: try `App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Router.extend`

Comment: lol you beat me by 12s

Comment: Just noticed that :P +1 tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  activate: ->
    App.callTheBeastsOfBurden()
```

Comment: I just came here to post this same thing. I solved my own problem, but not before the internet did. Thx man.